# Print Streamout With Another Way Using Java 7 For Using In Table Primefaces 4

Tags: java, java-7

In this https://github.com/thjanssen/ResultMapping/blob/master/src/test/java/org/thoughts/on/java/jpa/model/TestResultMapping.java there is many script for assign a value to the each object of course using java 8, like this one,

```
 results.stream().forEach((record) -> {
    Book book = (Book) record[0];
    Author author = (Author) record[1];
})
```

My target is using book and author to using in my primefaces 4 table, using this  nativequery for get think done.

My question is, how to print out ,append this in object, and get think right for  using in java 7 without stream()?

Thanks in advanced;